# clock cycle time of a "slt" instruction on single cycle processor

Tags: time, mips, clock, processor

I'm given timing information for

1. IF (fetch instruction)
2. ID (decode instruction)
3. EX (Execute)
4. MEM (Memory)
5. WB (write back)

I derived that the clock cycle time of a single cycle processor is just all 5 aforementioned timings summed up, since there is no pipe lining (I hope that's the right justification).

However, if I were to calculate the CC time of a specific instruction such as a *slt* instruction, then do I only add the times of the components that are relevant? For instance, *slt* doesn't have to access memory, so can I exclude that in my summation?

Comment: If you fed 1 million back to back slt instructions through, does it take 1 million and 5 clocks or 5 million clocks or somewhere in between to execute those 1 million slt instructions?

Comment: My guess is that it will take 4 million clock cycles, since it doesn't write to MEM. However, is that sufficient reasoning?

Comment: so when the first instruction is being executed the second is not being decoded and the third not being fetched?

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that it's pipe lined? If it doesn't specify it's pipe lined, do I assume so?

Comment: you say single cycle processor in the title then single processor in the question, which is it?  if single cycle then it does all those things in one cycle (other than waiting on memory if there is a memory cycle involved).

Comment: Sorry, I meant single cycle processor both times. I have edited the question.  And right, I understand that part. so does that mean, even if the critical path for a certain instruction is smaller than for another instruction, it will still take the same amount of time?

Comment: what is your definition of single cycle processor?

Comment: My definition is that in a single cycle processor, all instructions have the same CC length, determined by the longest path. Moreover, it takes one cycle per instruction. Thus, if all instructions happen in one cycle, and the time for one cycle is constant, then my conclusion is that all instructions take the same time, even if their path is small.

Comment: by that definition it would be four clocks for that instruction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each instruction in the single-cycle processor takes one clock cycle, so the clock cycle per instruction **CPI** is 1.

The cycle time `Tc` (clock period) depends on the critical path, logic design and that the component have delays. The delays are around picoseconds(`ps 10^-12`).

```
 Tc = t_pcqPC + 2t_mem + t_RFread + t_ALU + t_mux + t_RFsetup
```

An example here that show how to calculate the `Tc` for `lw`.

[image: delay]

The cycle time is

```
Tc = 30 + 2(250) + 150 + 200 + 25 + 20 = 925 ps
```

The clock period `Tc` is shorter for an R-type instruction than `lw` since they do not have memory access and `t_mem = 0`.
[Harris & Harris].